# get_posts() show always same title for all the posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show post of a specific category in the homepage of a Wordpress website using this piece of code:

```
    <?php $args = array('category' => 2);
            $news = get_posts($args);

            foreach ($news as $new) : setup_postdata($new); ?>

            <img data-slidecaption="<div class='caption'><h2><?php  the_title(); ?></h2><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>Leggi tutto</a></div>" src="">
    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div>
```

I have, for example, three posts with titles: Post 1, Post 2, Post 3.

The query works fine, and the content of each post is displayed correctly, but the title is always the one from the latest post. The same happens with the permalink. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I remember, `the_title()` should be used in `the loop`. It can be misleading but using `foreach` is not what WP define as 'the loop'.

Comment: it can make sense, but I tooke the code directly from the examples in the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Maybe there's another loop prior to this one.
Try adding `wp_reset_postdata();` before the `foreach`.

Comment: BTW, you put all this code into the `img` attribute (`data-slidecaption`) ? If yes, you should use different functions - what if there will be a quote character in your title or excerpt? You should escape it or look for another approach.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that and I'll change it, but that's not the main issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title()` shows the title of the current post / page active in the loop. `get_posts` makes an independent query, without affecting your main loop. Use

```
<?php echo $new->post_title; ?>
```

to display the news item's title.

Or, it would be even better to apply the correct filter aswell:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $new->post_title ); ?>
```

For the permalink, use

```
<?php echo get_permalink( $new->ID ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. The argument between the parenthesis should be the ID and not the post title, as Sunil Chaudhary did in his answer

Comment: Thats right. Although, since you already have the titles, there's actually no need to use get_the_title at all. I've edited appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<?php echo get_the_title($new->ID);?>` for title and 
use `<?php echo get_permalink($new->ID); ?>` for permalink in your loop, you will get your desired results. I am unable to figure out what you are trying to do, but follow my edits it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I'm trying to display the latest posts in a slideshow and use the title and excerpt in the caption. So, this solution works, but I still can't really understand why in the documentation the example is different: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts